# Anonymous Class return to parent method

Tags: java, return, return-value, anonymous-methods, anonymous-inner-class

Is it possible to have an anonymous inner class return a value for a method it is contained in? For example, I want to do some calculations in `something()`, which is an anonymous inner class, and have `doStuff()` return that value.

```
private int doStuff(){

    Foo foo = new Foo(new Bar.Example() {
            @Override
            public void something() {
                ...
                //return int for doStuff()
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: You can simply invoke a method on the anonymous class, e.g. `new Bar.DoStuff() { ... }.something()`. But please put a bit of effort into making your example code make sense, e.g. missing `new`, returning an `int` from a `void` method, making it clear what you're going to do to `foo` to get the value from that...

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I fixed the missing `new`, but the `return 1` was me trying to indicate that I wanted `doStuff` to return 1, not have void method return 1, I did tidy it up, however.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Instance final variable inside `doStuff()` method and assign the value inside the anonymous class.

Comment: You can't *re-assign* a final 'variable'. Do you mean final reference?

Comment: Yes, I meant to create a final reference variable like `int final value;` outside and to assign the value in the anonymous class like `value=1;`

Comment: That won't compile. Try it and see for yourself. Like I said earlier you can't reassign a final variable. Also your comment is ambiguous, you say reference variable but you are  using a primitive.